# localhost not working after installing laravel on OSX

Tags: php, macos, laravel, xampp, localhost

This problem only happens on OSX
I installed composer using the `curl -sS "https://getcomposer.org/installer" | php` command in Terminal and made the composer global then I created the laravel app using  `composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel cld` command and i restarted localhost and went to localhost/cld/public and I get the following error

> localhost is currently unable to handle this request.

I did the same thing in windows 10 and everything works fine.

**UPDATE**

I started to use Laravel Valet and it's amazing some useful resources

1. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/valet

2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBxIfN-GnnY&t=102s

Comment: Check your PHP version on OSX and see if it meets the requirement for your Laravel version. Also check file permissions and enable debugging  to get more details on the error.

Comment: Thanks, i have the latest version of PHP and all permissions are fine

Comment: Look into `Laravel Valet`. See if that solves your problem.

Comment: @RuChernChong Your sir deserve a cookie thank you so much valet is much easier than using XAMMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use laravel valet it's a life saver credit goes to Ru Chern Chong

Comment: Can you please provide a link for `Laravel Valet` or specific examples?

Comment: Here are some great resources 1. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/valet 2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBxIfN-GnnY

Comment: @BenderBending I'm guessing that you have composer installed but if you don't i would recommend installing it via Brew makes life much easier

Comment: Please consider adding your helpful resources and examples to your post by editing it. Thanks! @Yosef

Comment: Done :) @BenderBending

Comment: I meant to your answer post, but that's fine I guess.